# SharePoint Modern Site Customize Navigation Menu Design

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, communication-site, customization, header

I have created a SharePoint **modern Communication Online Site**, and I would like to customize the navigation menu and header the same as the below screenshot:

[image: Navigation Layout]

I would like to know how I can customize the navigation of my communication site the same as the above screenshot?

Can please someone explains in detail and provide an example to achieve the above?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the OOB settings provided by SharePoint Online, you can change the style of the header and top menu in a communication site by modifying **Change the look**, **Site theme**, **Header Layout** or **Background**, **Navigation** Menu style, etc.

See the detailed information here: [How to Customise Theme, Header, Footer and Navigation on Modern Communication sites?](https://www.beyondintranet.com/blog/how-to-customise-theme-header-footer-and-navigation-on-modern-communication-sites/)

If you are looking for further customization (with code for example), take a look at [Site designs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) feature which allows you to write customization in JSON files.

In addition, here is a site introducing different templates for SharePoint Online site for your reference:
https://lookbook.microsoft.com/